# Contact Form 7 content disappear after moving site online

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a WordPress site almost completed to live server.

The only problem I am facing is when I am renaming the URL in my database from localhost URL to live URL, I am not able to see contact us form details like From, To, Subject, HTML Body text.

All other things like widgets, pages content is fine but I am just not able to see these contents for Contact Form 7 when moving site to live by changing the URL and importing that database to live.

Why this is happening? What should I do? Or any proper method to do this?

Comment: How do you change the url? Have you tried using this tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ ?

Answer (score 2):

This happened when you changed the URL in the database.

When working in the localhost environment, your url was recorded in the database and was serialised.  Basically, the number of characters were counted and assigned to the url.

So, if your path was `http://localhost/my-site`, the number 24 is assigned to it in the database.

When you changed your url in the database to a new one and uploaded it, the number of characters more than likely did not match the original number assigned in the database.  If your new url is `http://my-site.com`, the number of characters being 18, then the original number of 24 does not match and this causes a conflict.

The database will update itself and as a result, theme options will reset, including your Contact Form 7 fields.

You will find a better explanation here, http://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-delicate-theme-options-lost-when-moving-to-new-domain, look to Chip Bennett's answers.

A workaround is to take a copy of your localhost database.  Keep that safe.

Then, go to Settings > General and change the WordPress Address(URL) and Site Address (URL) to your new path.  Now, take a copy of your database again.  This will used as your database for your new site.

Reupload your localhost database to make sure the localhost site is working again if you need it.

By using the New Database on the new site, your contact form 7 drtails (and any theme options if they are being used) will now come into the new site.

I have had this happen to me a lot before finding this and ever since I started using this method, all my information has come across perfectly.

Also check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

This plugin should fix the problem:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-contact-form-7-blank-fields/